# Rust, libzmq, client only send message, when followed by receive

Tags: rust, zeromq

I am testing Rust libzmq client

https://crates.io/crates/libzmq

https://docs.rs/libzmq/0.2.5/libzmq/struct.ClientBuilder.html

and stumbled upon this weird behavior.

This Client would not send the message:

```
use libzmq::{prelude::*, *, ServerBuilder, ClientBuilder, TcpAddr};

fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    
    let saddr = format!("{}:{}", "192.168.1.206","5540");
    println!("Strating client for {}", saddr);
    let addr2: TcpAddr = saddr.try_into().unwrap();
    
    let client = ClientBuilder::new()
        .connect(&addr2)
        .build().unwrap();
    client.send("test").unwrap();

    println!("Finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

this would send:

```
use libzmq::{prelude::*, *, ServerBuilder, ClientBuilder, TcpAddr};

fn main() -> Result<(), String> {
    
    let saddr = format!("{}:{}", "192.168.1.206","5540");
    println!("Strating client for {}", saddr);
    let addr2: TcpAddr = saddr.try_into().unwrap();
    
    let client = ClientBuilder::new()
        .connect(&addr2)
        .build().unwrap();
    client.send("test").unwrap();

    let mut msg = Msg::new();
    client.recv(&mut msg).unwrap();

    println!("Finished");
    Ok(())
}
```

For receiving I am using python server (but I tested on Rust as well):

```
import zmq
if __name__ == '__main__':

    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SERVER)
    socket.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5540")
    print("waiting for hand shake")
    m = socket.recv(copy=False)
    print("got it...")
    socket.send(b'READY', routing_id=m.routing_id)
    print("sent reply")
    socket.close()
    context.term()
```

Output on server side from code 1:

```
waiting for hand shake
[blocked]
```

Output on server side from code 2:

```
waiting for hand shake
got it...
sent reply
```

using this version for Rust:

```
[dependencies]
libzmq = "0.2.5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `libzmq` crate is just a wrapper for the [`libzmq` C library](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq). In the [documentation for the C library](https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq/blob/master/doc/zmq_msg_send.txt), you will find this note:

> NOTE: A successful invocation of *zmq_msg_send()* does not indicate that the
> message has been transmitted to the network, only that it has been queued on
> the 'socket' and 0MQ has assumed responsibility for the message.

In your first example, since the program exits immediately after calling `send`, the message is still in the `libzmq` queue and has not been transmitted yet. In your second example, the message gets transmitted while your program is waiting in the `recv` call.